# How to highlight references of local functions and variables?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want my local function names (those declared in the current file and picked by font-lock-function-name-face) and my variable names (font-lock-variable-name-face) to be highlighted across the whole buffer. Currently font-lock-function-name-face and font-lock-variable-name-face highlight only declarations and not references.

Comment: So do you just want to change the background color of `font-lock-function-name-face` and `font-lock-variable-name-face` then?  I feel like there's a nuance here that I'm not following in your original question.

Comment: @cyberbisson currently only declarations are highlighted and not references.

Comment: Oh ok, got it, thanks!

Comment: I think that would be very confusing for languages where you can import names from other files like Cʼs `#include` or Pythonʼs `import`. It would be even more confusing when names are *just there*, like in Elisp (you donʼt need to import anything for a function defined outside your file to be available).

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai How is it confusing? I want syntax highlighting to distinguish between these two fundamentally different scopes.

Comment: @xged ah, in that case i misunderstood your question. Sorry for the noise!